# Having an AND operator function 'simultaneously' on a per row basis SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table as a starting point, we will call it `table1`:

| id | Key | Some_Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | Event1 |
| 02 | 1 | Event2 |
| 03 | 1 | Event2 |
| 04 | 2 | Event1 |
| 05 | 2 | Event2 |
| 06 | 3 | Event1 |
| 07 | 3 | Event2 |
| 08 | 3 | Event1 |
| 09 | 3 | Event2 |
| 10 | 4 | Event1 |
| 11 | 4 | Event1 |
| 12 | 4 | Event2 |

What I want to do is to display the event and which event succeeds that event on a per `Key` basis. However, I also want to filter out scenarios where an `Event2` is succeeded by another `Event2` for example if you look at the records with a `Key` of 1. The desired output would be as follows:

| id | Key | Some_Event | Next_Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | Event1 | Event2 |
| 02 | 1 | Event2 | NULL |
| 04 | 2 | Event1 | Event2 |
| 05 | 2 | Event2 | NULL |
| 06 | 3 | Event1 | Event2 |
| 07 | 3 | Event2 | Event1 |
| 08 | 3 | Event1 | Event2 |
| 09 | 3 | Event2 | NULL |
| 10 | 4 | Event1 | Event1 |
| 11 | 4 | Event1 | Event2 |
| 12 | 4 | Event2 | NULL |

I have written the following query which has some flaws. I am not sure if I have went the best route but I am struggling to filter out the scenarios where an `Event2` is succeeded by another `Event2`:

```
SELECT    id, 
          Key, 
          IIF(t.Some_Event = 'Event1', t.NEXT_EVENT, NULL) AS Next_Event
FROM      (
            SELECT LEAD(Some_Event, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Key) AS NEXT_EVENT
            FROM table1
          ) t
WHERE NOT `Some_Event` = `Event2` AND t.Some_Event = t.NEXT_EVENT
ORDER BY  t.Key
```

With the way I have done it, the issue is in my where clause. The `AND` operator is functioning in a seperate manner, what I want is if `Some_Event = Event2` then if `Some_event = Next_Event` filter it out. I am not sure how to solve for this, I assume I am using the `AND` operator in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Given the application of the `LEAD` window function that you've already done. You can use a `CASE` statement to assign NULL values where `Some_Event = Next_Event = 'Event2'`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           LEAD(Some_Event) OVER (
               PARTITION BY [Key] 
               ORDER     BY [id]) AS Next_Event
    FROM table1
)
SELECT [id], 
       [Key],
       [Some_Event],
       CASE WHEN NOT ([Next_Event] = 'Event2' AND [Some_Event] = 'Event2')
            THEN [Next_Event]
       END AS [Next_Event]
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7c5546b51f878d286b49022818cab59).